# Odd rendering for font-awsome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

From time to time after page refresh fontawesome icons get this rendered this way:

[image]

When they should look like this:

[image]

Is there anything I am missing my html or CSS?

This is the HTML to display each of those menu options is as simple as:

```
<li class=""><a ui-sref="Resources" title="Resources">
                        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-globe"></i>
                        <span class="menu-item-parent ng-binding">Resources</span>
                    <b class="collapse-sign"><em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></em></b></a>
                </li>
```

The parent elements for the menu are:

```
<aside id="left-panel"><nav nav-menu="" stopwatch="true">
   <ul><li><!--menu time --></li>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in dev console?

Comment: No, console is cleaned.

Comment: Can you share your html ?

Comment: @NigelFds I just added the item itself if you need a bigger scope I can share it too

Answer (score 1):

It seems something like mojibake. It could depend on the files (css and html) or document encoding. The file one should be utf-8 without bom.